# How to make Excel completely Full screen, hiding the Title-bar of Window & the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: vba, excel

My current code allows me to go to full screen without any problem, but still, I need complete immersive mode by-

> 1. Hiding the Title bar of Excel
> 2. Stopping the Excel Flash screen on startup
> 3. Hiding the Windows Taskbar.

Is there a VBA Code for that? Please help. 
Thanks in advance :)

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).WindowState = xlMaximized
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize Excel
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize the workbook in Excel


End Sub
```

Comment: Use google and you will probably find the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this cannot be done with VBA, as the VBA interpreter runs AFTER Excel has loaded.

You need to use a command line switch to start Excel.

Here is Microsoft's solution: start Excel with the `/e` option.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291288/description-of-the-startup-switches-for-excel